# StoredProcedure: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL server to store the procedure.

I facing the error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'"

and following is my query:

```
set @SQL= 'select pushto as MSISDN,pushprice as Price,pushdate as DateTime,pushtext as Message from '+@tblname+' WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE '+@sqldate + @scodelist+ @clientlist + @piclist +' INNER JOIN INAPremium..INA_Keyword K on R.keyid = K.keyid WHERE '+@sqldate
+ @scodelist+ @clientlist + @piclist + @DNType + @pkeywordlist + @seckeywordlist +' order by pushdate desc'
```

Need you all help hand.
thank you.

Comment: You can only have one `WHERE` clause and it needs to come after all of the `FROM` with `JOIN`s.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific!

Answer (score 0):

Your posted query is way wrong. You have used `WHERE` before `INNER JOIN` which actually should other way round. Moreover, you have multiple `WHERE` clauses

```
from '+@tblname+' WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE '+@sqldate + @scodelist+ @clientlist + @piclist +' 
INNER JOIN INAPremium..INA_Keyword K on R.keyid = K.keyid
```

Should be

```
from '+@tblname+' WITH (NOLOCK)      
INNER JOIN INAPremium..INA_Keyword K on R.keyid = K.keyid
WHERE '+@sqldate + @scodelist+ @clientlist + @piclist +'
```

Answer (score 0):

You Syntax must be `from ... inner join ... where`.

Something like that:

```
set @SQL= 'select pushto as MSISDN,pushprice as Price,pushdate as DateTime,pushtext as Message 
from '+@tblname+' WITH (NOLOCK)  +
' INNER JOIN INAPremium..INA_Keyword K on R.keyid = K.keyid 
WHERE '+@sqldate + 
+ @scodelist+ @clientlist + @piclist + @DNType + @pkeywordlist + @seckeywordlist +' order by pushdate desc'
```

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective it is syntax error.

You have double WHERE, once after WITH (NOLOCK) second after INNER JOIN.

Please try this code:

```
set @SQL= '
select 
    pushto as MSISDN,
    pushprice as Price,
    pushdate as DateTime,
    pushtext as Message 
    from '+@tblname+' 
    WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN INAPremium..INA_Keyword K on R.keyid = K.keyid 
    WHERE '+@sqldate+ @scodelist+ @clientlist + @piclist + @DNType + @pkeywordlist + @seckeywordlist +' 
    order by pushdate desc'
```